# Docker - pull from docker repo fails (EOF / 403) but download from RH repo works

Tags: image, docker, eof, pull

System info : 
RHEL 7.1 (fresh install)
Docker 1.6.2
We're using the Docker rpm provided by RH in their "bonus" dvd's.

Issue : 
When I pull an image through docker, it **only** works when it's on the Red Hat repo.

```
# docker pull openshift3/mysql-55-rhel7
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/mysql-55-rhel7 
...
bb8bf2124de9: Download complete
65de4a13fc7c: Download complete
85400654aa47: Download complete
c537da9944e0: Download complete
6d97b1e161bb: Download complete
0d0dc8d923d6: Download complete
e4ba106b746b: Download complete
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/mysql-55-rhel7:latest
```

When I pull an image from Docker repo... it fails. But - which is imho really weird - with different errors.

So first I pull **httpd**

```
# docker pull httpd
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/httpd ... not found latest: Pulling from docker.io/httpd
64e5325c0d9d: Pulling fs layer
bf84c1d84a8f: Download complete
6c1a7f5286ab: Download complete
…
ee4d515e8896: Download complete
de94ed779434: Download complete
de94ed779434: **Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/httpd, ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: unexpected EOF**
FATA[0040] Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/httpd, ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: unexpected EOF
```

But, pulling the **hello-world** gives

```
# docker pull hello-world
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/hello-world ... not found
latest: Pulling from docker.io/hello-world
a8219747be10: Pulling fs layer
a8219747be10: Error pulling dependent layers
91c95931e552: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/hello-world,  Server error: Status 403 while fetching image layer (a821974FATA[0010] Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/hello-world, Server error: Status 403 while fetching image layer (a8219747be10611d65b7c693f48e7222c0bf54b5df8467d3f99003611afa1fd8)
```

I'm on a corporate network and applied what's in [this blog](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/11/using-docker-with-a-proxy.html) concerning proxies and certificate to get it running.

Comment: We traced the error and added `https://*.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/*` to our proxy rules. Are there other URL's where Docker stores the images?

Comment: It sounds like you have IT Security that believe that playing whitelist-wack-a-mole constitutes a reason to draw a salary. Suffice it to say that where the docker hub registry is stored is an implementation, not contractural, detail.
Depending on implementation details is fragile and error prone. Play stupid games, win stupid prizes.

Answer (score 3):

```
service docker stop

rm -r /var/lib/docker/*

service docker start
```

Worked for me. Note that this will very likely clear docker

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can do to mitigate this :

1. If you're seeing this error while pulling large images from private
   repo, It could mean that the private repo is busy, as someone else
   might be pulling at the same time.
2. If the size of the image which you're pulling is huge and your machine is       under-powered you still
   could see this issue, even though you could be pulling from a public
   repo.
3. If none of the above applies to you, then I think you've hit a
   strange bug in docker 1.7, Your best bet is to upgrade the client
   version to 1.11 or recent.

Answer (score 0):

I also received `unexpected EOF` when pulling a large image (>2GB). However, the answer for us was to increase the size of the file system where the incoming images were being cached before being moved on to where the docker daemon stored them.

Sounds irrelevant to the real issue of this question but it might be useful for someone else to check in future.